# Limit of a function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Compute:  $ \lim_{ x \rightarrow 1^{-}} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n(1+x^n)} $

I compute: $$  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{ x \rightarrow 1^{-}}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n(1+x^n)}\\
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n} = +\infty $$

And. I think it is false.

Can you help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

**Big Hint:** $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}=\ln(2)$$

To prove this result you can use [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem) on
$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
for all $x\in]-1,1[$.